# Firebase allow insertion within TimeStamp

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-security

I tried to allow data insertion within timestamp about 10 sec since my program start, I have the following data structure

- data

  - items
  - time

    - time

on starting the program I save the current timestamp in `time` as following

```
firebaseRef.child("time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, listener);
firebaseRef.child("time").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Long timestamp = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        System.out.println(timestamp);

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("time", timestamp);
        firebaseRef.child("time").setValue(map, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    }
});
```

and I made the following security-rule

```
"items": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.parent().child('time').child('time').val() + 10000 >= now" 
}
```

But it didn't work and I got permission denied. What's wrong with my rule?

Comment: What does `firebaseRef` point to?

Comment: Your security rule says time has to be greater than now + 10000, but Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP will set it to now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen firebaseRef it's my app's reference `Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("my app url")`

Comment: @Kato Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I suppose now refers to the server time and the time's value refers to my program start time. I compare to see if the insertion operation is within 10 seconds from start time. Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems certainly is that you're initializing with:

```
firebaseRef.child("time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, listener);
```

This sets the value of `time` to a long.

```
{
  "time": 1460776272703
}
```

But then:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("time", timestamp);
ref.child("time").setValue(map, listener);
```

You're calling `setValue()` on `time` then passing in a map with a `time` key, so end up writing `time/time`.

```
{
  "time": {
    "time": 1460776272703
  }
}
```

Even if this is intentional, it seems like a bad idea to change the data structure like that. For example, in the simulator I quickly ran into an error message like this:

> Type Error: + only operates on numbers and strings.

Because it was trying to evaluate a JSON object (`/time` in the second snippet above) as a numeric value.

My working snippet is simpler:

```
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/36658910");
    ref.child("time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, listener);
    /*ref.child("time").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            Long timestamp = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(timestamp);
            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(timestamp);
        }
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
    });*/
```

I run it like this so test seeding the location and then I do another run where I disable the initial `setValue()` and enable the listener, to test updates.

The corresponding security rules:

```
"time": {
  ".write": true,
  ".validate": "(!data.exists() && newData.val() == now) || newData.child('time').val() + 100000 >= now"
}
```

You'll note that I have separate cases for writing the initial value (which must be done with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to match `now`) and the updates (which must be within 100 seconds after the previous write).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know the problem but `firebaseRef.child("time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, listener)` doesn't set any value, I've it tried it a lot, that's why I had to save the time myself.  I suppose `now` refers to the current time on server and the time's value refers to my program start time so. When I insert an item I compare the time value with `now` to make sure difference is within some specified milliseconds but that's also not working. Maybe it's my fault and I misunderstand the timestamp and `now`.

Comment: Your initial `setValue()` fails for multiple reasons. You have a `time/time` nesting in there and it doesn't allow for setting the initial value. My security rules and code above work. Try them and then see what I changed from yours.